# remove duplicate strings in a List in Java

Tags: java, collections, set

Update:
I guess `HashSet.add(Object obj)` does not call `contains`. is there a way to implement what I want(remove dup strings ignore case using `Set`)?

Original question:
trying to remove dups from a list of String in java, however in the following code `CaseInsensitiveSet.contains(Object ob)` is not getting called, why?

```
public static List<String> removeDupList(List<String>list, boolean ignoreCase){
    Set<String> set = (ignoreCase?new CaseInsensitiveSet():new LinkedHashSet<String>());
    set.addAll(list);

    List<String> res = new Vector<String>(set);
    return res;
}


public class CaseInsensitiveSet  extends LinkedHashSet<String>{

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj){
        //this not getting called.
        if(obj instanceof String){

            return super.contains(((String)obj).toLowerCase());
        }
        return super.contains(obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use code formatting rather than using `<pre>` statements.

Comment: Why did you wipe out my edits?

Comment: Do you want to retain the order of the strings in the list? If so, for duplicates, do you want to take the position of the first or the last occurrence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`contains` is not called as LinkedHashSet is not implemented that way.

If you want add() to call contains() you will need to override it as well.

The reason it is not implemented this way is that calling contains first would mean you are performing two lookups instead of one which would be slower.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
        Set set = new TreeSet(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        set.addAll(list);
        return new ArrayList(set);
```

**UPDATE** but as Tom Anderson mentioned it does not preserve the initial order, if this is really an issue try

```
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        String s = i.next();
        if (set.contains(s)) {
            i.remove();
        }
        else {
            set.add(s);
        }
    }
```

prints

```
[2, 1]
```

Comment: If the asker doesn't care about preserving the order in the list, then this is an excellent answer. If he does, sadly, it is merely a good one.

Answer (score 3):

`add()` method of `LinkedHashSet` do not call `contains()` internally else your method would have been called as well.

Instead of a `LinkedHashSet`, why dont you use a `SortedSet` with a case insensitive comparator 
? With the [String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) comparator

Your code is reduced to

```
public static List<String> removeDupList(List<String>list, boolean ignoreCase){
    Set<String> set = (ignoreCase?new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):new LinkedHashSet<String>());
    set.addAll(list);

    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(set);
    return res;
}
```

If you wish to preserve the Order, as @tom anderson specified in his comment, you can use an auxiliary LinkedHashSet for the order.

You can try adding that element to TreeSet, if it returns true also add it to LinkedHashSet else not.

```
public static List<String> removeDupList(List<String>list){
        Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        List<String> orderedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str : list){
             if(sortedSet.add(str)){ // add returns true, if it is not present already else false
                 orderedList.add(str);
             }
        }
        return orderedList;
    }
```

Comment: As i commented on Evgeniy's answer, this doesn't preserve the order of the strings in the list, which might or might not matter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the code to preserve order of the elements.

Comment: Rather than building up `orderedSet` and then converting it to an `ArrayList`, you could just build up the `ArrayList` directly. The fact that `orderedSet` is a set is not actually needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
            for(String s : c) {
            if(! this.contains(s)) {
                this.add(s);
            }
        }
        return super.addAll(c);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        //Do your checking here
//      return super.contains(o);
    }
```

This will make sure the contains method is called if you want the code to go through there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using a `HashSet` of the strings for deduplication, but building the result list directly:

```
public static List<String> removeDupList(List<String> list, boolean ignoreCase) {
    HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
    ArrayList<String> deduplicatedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String string : list) {
        if (seen.add(ignoreCase ? string.toLowerCase() : string)) {
            deduplicatedList.add(string);
        }
    }
    return deduplicatedList;
}
```

This is fairly simple, makes only one pass over the elements, and does only a lowercase, a hash lookup, and then a list append for each element.